# Initial Event in Windows Console

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I'm creating a Windows Console application written in VB.NET and I have a few processes that need to be called only once during the lifetime of the application. If it was an ASP.NET application, I put these in the Appliction_Start method of the Global.asax.vb file. Since there isn't a Global.asax.vb for Console applications, is there an event I could handle that allows me to call my functions before Main is called?

Comment: Why can't Main do that?

Comment: I was trying to abstract it out of Main so I more easily copy it over to other projects, such as Windows Service I was working.

Comment: Then write a function to do the things you need done. Now you can take that function wherever you want. Call it first in main.

Comment: That is what I've done. I was looking for alternative approach, to keep implementation of housekeeping items out of Main. It sounds like I just need to use Main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main is the first method where you can grab the needed information / inizialize global stuff.
Why would you need an earlier point? The only thing that is different to Application_Start is that no other method is called automatically (unlike in a web application where the site is opened and the code executed).

Answer (score 2):

Is there a problem with just calling them first **in** main?